# Displaying only radios with data-socket as set by previous radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a custom computer builder for my site like you see on dell and the likes.

Basically you can choose you processor, the html for them look like this:

```
<div class="process_intel_options" style="display:block">
    <label class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="processor_options" value="124" data-price="195.82"  data-socket="1366"  class="calculation-item"  id="intel_options_0" checked="checked"  />
        Intel Core i7 960 3.20Ghz (Nehalem) <span class="item_price positive">+0</span> </label>
    <br />
    <label class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="processor_options" value="149" data-price="250.00"  data-socket="1155"  class="calculation-item"  />
        Processor socket 1155 <span class="item_price positive">+0</span> </label>
    <br />
    <label class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="processor_options" value="125" data-price="359.99"  data-socket="1366"  class="calculation-item"  />
        Intel Core i7 980 3.33Ghz (Gulftown) <span class="item_price positive">+0</span> </label>
    <br />
</div>
<div class="process_amd_options" style="display:none">
    <label class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="processor_options" value="126" data-price="133.32"  data-socket="am3"  class="calculation-item"  id="amd_options_0"  />
        AMD Bulldozer FX-8 Eight Core 8120 3.10Ghz <span class="item_price positive">+0</span> </label>
    <br />
    <label class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="processor_options" value="127" data-price="162.99"  data-socket="am3"  class="calculation-item"  />
        AMD Bulldozer FX-8 Eight Core 8150 3.60Ghz <span class="item_price positive">+0</span> </label>
</div>
```

Notice the attribute `data-socket`.

You can then select the motherboard:

```
<div class="mobo_options">
    <label class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="motherboard_options" value="145" data-price="178.00" data-socket="1155"  class="calculation-item"  id="mobo_options_0" checked="checked"  />
        Motherboard 1 socket 1155 <span class="item_price positive">+0</span> </label>
    <br />
    <label class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="motherboard_options" value="146" data-price="180.00" data-socket="1155"  class="calculation-item"  />
        Motherboard 2 socket 1155 <span class="item_price positive">+0</span> </label>
    <br />
    <label class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="motherboard_options" value="147" data-price="190.00" data-socket="1366"  class="calculation-item"  />
        Motherboard 3 socket 1366 <span class="item_price positive">+0</span> </label>
    <br />
    <label class="option">
        <input type="radio" name="motherboard_options" value="148" data-price="200.00" data-socket="2011"  class="calculation-item"  />
        Motherboard 4 socket 2011 <span class="item_price positive">+0</span> </label>
    <br />
</div>
```

This also has data-socket.

I'm looking for a query script that will only show the motherboards that have the correct socket type as the processors, for example, if a processor is selected with `data-socket="1155"` then only motherboards with `data-socket="1155"` will be shown (also the first one needs to be selected in case they select a different processor.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
$('input:radio[name="processor_options"]').change(function(e) {
    var socket = $(this).data('socket');
    $('div.mobo_options input:radio[data-socket!="' + socket + '"]').hide();
    $('div.mobo_options input:radio[data-socket="' + socket + '"]').show().get(0).checked = true;
});
```

Note that it only hides the `<input type="radio">` elements, not the text that accompanies them. You might want to wrap it in another element (such as an `<li>` inside an `<ul>`) that you could hide instead, so the accompanying text is hidden as well.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GyHrG/)

---

Just noticed you have the `<input>` elements wrapped in `<label>` elements, so you could use the following code instead to hide the text as well:

```
$('input:radio[name="processor_options"]').change(function(e) {
    var socket = $(this).data('socket');
    $('div.mobo_options input:radio[data-socket!="' + socket + '"]').closest('label').hide();
    $('div.mobo_options input:radio[data-socket="' + socket + '"]').closest('label').show().end().get(0).checked = true;
});
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GyHrG/1/)

Comment: Hi, that works but I'm struggling to implent it to my main code, can you take a look at this fiddle please?
http://jsfiddle.net/Genyx/rnkFr/1/

Comment: The code in my answer hinges on the fact that `this` is the radio element that has been changed. Since that's not the case in your code (you're calling it as a function, and not only as a result of an event), I've modified it to select the currently selected radio button with `name="processor_options"` and use that, rather than `this`. [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anthonygrist/rnkFr/2/)

Comment: Sorry, but in your example you can't select a different motherboard if there are 2 or more, do you know whats causing this?

Comment: There's a call to `SelectMobo()` (which handles selecting the first available motherboard for that processor) at the end of `CalculatePrice()` (which gets called every time you click on any element with the class `calculation-item`).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find all the motherboards with `data-socket="someValue"` you could try this if you are using jQuery

```
$('[data-socket="someValue"][name="motherboard_options"]')
```

This will give you all options with the name motherboard_options and socket value 'someValue'